# PHP dynamic require

Tags: php, require

The main issue it's still the same:

This is my proyect

```
/
| index.php
|-test1
   | test.php
```

The test.php

```
<?php

echo $variable;


?>
```

The index.php

```
<?php

$variable = "<br>index";

echo 'test<br>';

$full_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/test1";
$adm_extension = array( "php");

if (is_dir($full_path)) {
    if (($handle = opendir($full_path))) {
        while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
            if (is_file($full_path . '/' . $file)) {
                $item_path = $full_path . '/' . $file;
                $extension = pathinfo($item_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if (in_array($extension, $adm_extension)) {
                        require $item_path;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it's works like a charm, the output is:

```
test

index
```

If i want to encapsulate this functionality in a function like this:

index1.php

```
$variable = "<br>index";

echo 'test<br>';

$full_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/test1";
$adm_extension = array( "php" );

function rTest($full_path, $adm_extension){
if (is_dir($full_path)) {
    if (($handle = opendir($full_path))) {
        while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
            if (is_file($full_path . '/' . $file)) {
                $item_path = $full_path . '/' . $file;
                $extension = pathinfo($item_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if (in_array($extension, $adm_extension)) {
                        require $item_path;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

rTest($full_path, $adm_extension);
```

I got this:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: variable in C:\wamp\www\sandbox\test1\test.php on line 3
```

Any clue??

Comment: Not sure it has something to do with autoloading. You are doing `$app->get` on line 3 but $app is not defined.

Comment: The $app it's always defined in the index.php, the weird thing it's when I manually do the require it's work. When it's dynamic not. 
Manually = defined $app
Dynamic = undefined $app

Comment: @Laurent I made some tests and issue isnt in the framework though now i think it's 'in' php, fml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a friend help me to solve it out.

It's was a really dumb error. The problem was when I made the require, it was made in the function scope.

For my solution I do something like this:

```
function rTest($full_path, $adm_extension){
    $paths = array();
    if (is_dir($full_path)) {
        if (($handle = opendir($full_path))) {
            while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
                if (is_file($full_path . '/' . $file)) {
                    $item_path = $full_path . '/' . $file;
                    $extension = pathinfo($item_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        if (in_array($extension, $adm_extension)) {
                             $paths[] = $item_path;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $paths;
}

foreach(rTest($full_path, $adm_extension) as $path){
    require $path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your script probably, when going through files, opens `test.php` before `index1.php` so `$variable` isn't defined yet

test it:

```
function rTest($full_path, $adm_extension){
if (is_dir($full_path)) {
    if (($handle = opendir($full_path))) {
        while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
            if (is_file($full_path . '/' . $file)) {
                $item_path = $full_path . '/' . $file;
                $extension = pathinfo($item_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if (in_array($extension, $adm_extension)) {
                        echo $item_path.'<br />';
                        require $item_path;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: hmm I seems imposible because i call the function rTest in the index1.php so the file itself its opened and i call the function after i had declared the $variable